# how to get indirect link of google search result

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, url, google-search

I want to get indirect link of google search result .

after search in google if Right-clicking the result link changed to somthing like this

```
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCkQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FHI&ei=y8mSVJb3HYqlNqvBgIgM&usg=AFQjCNEWA_V3hjoVAu_W7mu3fbN6Q4n0Lw&sig2=dDRuO4YH9VIDXgQoZJH4tQ&bvm=bv.82001339,d.eXY
```

and if don't click

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HI
```

all because for this function in ***onmousedown***

```
<a class="l" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','4','AFQjCNGl8DlEwS7SQ8vWxBPyiZBUbUj0Yg','Nlw9cdFH31TadhaL8C4A‌​8g','0CDEQFjAD')" href="http://....">
```

anyway i want to get indirect link i try for right click first using javascript and then get link but i cant

this is my sample code :

```
                HtmlElement script1 = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
                HtmlElement script2 = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
                HtmlElement script3 = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
                HtmlElement script4 = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
                script1.SetAttribute("rightc1", "function rightc1(thiselements){var element = thiselements;var e = element.ownerDocument.createEvent('MouseEvents');e.initMouseEvent('contextmenu', true, true,element.ownerDocument.defaultView, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false,false, false, false,2, null);return !element.dispatchEvent(e);}");
                script2.SetAttribute("rightc2", "function rightc2(thiselements){$('#thiselements').trigger({type: 'mousedown',which: 3});}");
                script3.SetAttribute("rightc3", "function rightc3(thiselements){$('#thiselements').trigger({type: 'mouseup',which: 3});}");
                script4.SetAttribute("rightc4", "function rightc4(thiselements){$('#thiselements').trigger({type: 'mousedown',which: 3}).trigger({type: 'mouseup',which: 3});}");
```

then append to the link

```
link.AppendChild(script1);
```

and run script with this code

```
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("rightc1", args);
```

also i try with

```
link.InvokeMember("Click");
```

and after redirect to new page want to get link !

but all not work for me ! and return direct link like this

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HI
```

what is wrong ? how can i get indirect link ? possible  ? any other idea ?

kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

Just trigger the `mousedown` event for a result `<a>` tag - wither by hand or by code - then read the tag's `href` again - it will contain the Google redirected link.